# Apache Ignite CPU issue

Tags: spring, ignite, spring-cache

I'm going to implement Ignite into my hight loaded Spring application as a Spring cache for replication between nodes. 
But I faced with a CPU performance issue when I was testing on some percentage of users in production. 
For testing, I used 4 servers. 2 in client mode (with Spring) and 2 in server mode. 
Each server has 8 CPU and 8GB RAM. 
Nodes with Spring Cache are configured Dynamic Near Cache to avoid network overload.

I'm new in Ignite configuration, probably I made some mistake. 
Do you have any thoughts about the reason for the CPU performance issue?

Screenshots with comparing server with Ignite and without:
[the test with 5% of users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PHBU.png)

Comment: Can you interpret your charts for us? I don't understand what color coding means here and what is the scenario and how the problem is apparent.

Comment: Yes, server names are hidden. Green and yellow are old production nodes with ~95% users and blue is a new node with Ignite + Spring Cache and ~5% users. I attached these charts just to show the problem visually. As we can see, the server with 5% consumes CPU more than the same server without Ignite with 74% users

Comment: Have you tried profiling with e.g. JFR to see where the time gets spent?

Comment: Yes, I profiled with YourKit, but I didn't find the reason yet. All App methods are working slowly. I'll analyze more deeply soon

Comment: The first guess is, are you sure you are not starting an Ignite node on every API call?

Comment: No, Ignite node starts once on spring start. I configured according to this manual - https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/spring-caching

Comment: Do you have any updates?